# K&R Exercise 2-4

Tags: c, loops

I'm writing K&R Exercise 2-4: **Write an alternative version of squeeze(s1,s2) that deletes each character in s1 that matches any character in the string s2.**

My code (correct version):

```
void squeeze(char str[], char sub[]) {
  int i = 0;

  if (sub[0] == '\0')
    return;

  for (int j = 0, cnt = 0; str[j] != '\0'; ++j) {

    while (sub[cnt] != '\0' && str[j + cnt] == sub[cnt])
      ++cnt;

    if (sub[cnt] == '\0') {
      j = j + cnt;
      cnt = 0;
    }

    str[i++] = str[j];
  }

  str[i] = '\0';
}
```

What I don't understand is that I always got a wrong answer when I put `cnt++` in while expression as below:

```
while (sub[cnt] != '\0' && str[j + cnt] == sub[cnt++])
  ;
```

I checked the associativity of `==` is **Left-to-right**, I expect it'll check `str[j + cnt] == sub[cnt]` first then do `cnt++` same logic with my correct version code above.

gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)

Could someone explain what's the difference with these two?

Comment: One difference: When the second condition is false the first version will not increment `cnt` whereas the second version will.

Comment: `str[j + cnt] == sub[cnt++]` It is unspecified which of the two expressions on either side of `==` is evaluated first, and operator associativity has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @kaylum ahh, right! then `cnt` won't start from `0` any more, thank you for resolving it!

Comment: @dxiv oh?! I though the associativity of `==` is **Left-to-right** means it'll get the value of `str[j + cnt]` first, then get the value of `sub[cnt++]`, then compare if they're equal.

Comment: @CaChen Left-to-right associativity means that `a == b == c` parses as `(a == b) == c`. But there is no guarantee that `a`, `b`, `c` will be evaluated in any particular order, see [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order).

Comment: @dxiv got it! Thanks for your carefully explanation.